# Hibernate get child relations that fulfill relations only

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a relation as follows

Employee -> job (one to one)

Job -> salary (one to many)

which is translated to the following classes

```
public class Employee
@OneToOne
Job job; ....'

public class Job
@OneToMany()
List<Salary> salaries;
```

I want to obtain those employees that have a certain job which have certain salaries therefore a criteria for hibernate can be return to perform this task as follows

```
createCriteria(Employee.class).createAlias("job", "job")
                .createAlias("job.salaries", "salaries").add(Restrictions.gt("salaries.sum", 5000))
```

which works fine but what I also want is that only those values greater than 5000 to be available and loading all salaries is this possible with hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have to the Salaries entities fetched as part of the result.

In that case try this:

```
createCriteria(Employee.class)
.createAlias("job", "job")
.createAlias("job.salaries", "salaries")
.setFetchMode("job", FetchMode.JOIN)
.setFetchMode("salaries", FetchMode.JOIN)
.add(Restrictions.gt("salaries.sum", 5000));
```

of course you need to fetch Job entities also in thee process.

**Update**

Try adding

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "job")
List<Salary> salaries;
```

to this mapping. I assume that Salary entity has a `Job job` field (which is a properly mapped with @ManytToOne and @JoinColumn).

Comment: What I want is that the salaries with sum greater than 5000 only exist in the list but currently I get all salaries that are related to this job

Comment: still the same result is obtained

Comment: Could you please share your models and DAOs to save some of my time. I am trying to find out the answer.

Are you ok if we use HQL?

Regards,
Krishan